# Create Hot-Key to insert code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

On almost all of my vb files, at some point I have to enter some code which is about 30 characters long. Rather than me having to type all this out, or copy/paste from an existing file, I was wondering whether its possible, in Visual Studio 2010, to assign a Hot-Key to this value such as `Ctrl+A+B` which will paste this code in for me?

Comment: Can't you just use code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Johannes-Rössel's suggestion I had a look into Code Snippets and have now been able to set up my Visual Studio so that when I click `[Keyword]+Tab+Tab` it inserts my code!

I did this using Code Snippets and the Shortcut facility they have. Very useful!